# Prove that in a *nonlinear* circuit, adding resistor between equipotential terminals draws no current

Tags: thevenin, linear, non-linear

If a circuit is linear, then you can use Thevenin equivalence to prove that if a port of a circuit has an open-circuit voltage of 0 V (the two terminals are at the same potential), then the resistor will not draw any current.

What if the entire circuit is nonlinear? Intuitively I think the fact still holds but Thevenin equivalence can't prove it anymore. Is there a counterexample to this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework without a showing of attempts at solution.

Comment: Hi @MathKeepsMeBusy, this is in fact not a homework question. I would be very surprised if any modern circuits classes ask questions similar to this at all since nonlinear circuit theory is not commonly taught in my experience. I certainly didn't find any reference to a question of this sort anywhere, which is why I asked it on this forum.

Comment: OK. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: I'd like it if some teacher *did*, though. Get their students thinking.

Comment: How can you prove that a ball won't start rolling along a level surface unless you push it?

Comment: I think it’s fairly self evident assuming resistance > 0.

Comment: What I'm specifically interested in is a proof using the axioms of circuit theory; like I said, I agree that intuitively I believe this fact is true.

Comment: If you assume that the nonlinear behavior is continuous it will be linear over some region near the current operating point so you can use Thevenin near the 0V. With resistance >0 nothing can happen.

Comment: On the other hand, in a real circuit it might not be true: thermal noise, capacitive and inductive coupling could upset a sensitive circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a very simple circuit -

[image]

And non linear element has V-I characteristic

$$\begin{array}{ll}
    V=V_o\cos(I)&\mathrm{if}\,I<\frac{\pi}{2},\,\mathrm{else}\\
    I=\frac{\pi}{2}&\mathrm{if}\,V<0.
\end{array}$$

We can draw V-I characteristic of non linear element as -

[image]

Now introducing a load  resistor  ,we have new circuit something like -
[image]

And now we find out what will be current through load resistor will be for different values of load resistor -

[image]

**Conclusion**   -without load resistor the potential between two terminals are same (equipotential ) but as soon as you introduce a new load resistor between two equipotential terminals , current will flow through resistor and hence in non linear circuits zero  open circuit voltage doesn't ensure zero current if we introduce a resistor between equipotential terminals!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example- but shouldn't the V-I curve of the nonlinear component be flipped about the I axis? Since for the open-circuit condition to have 0 volts at the open port, the voltage across the device should be Vo, not -Vo, I think.

Comment: @knzy yeah , whatever you wrote is absolutely correct ,it should be in 1st quadrant , I'll edit it ! But conclusion doesn't change .

Comment: This is a great example thanks a lot for bringing it up, and I think it actually graphically confirms what I wrote in another comment, which is that with some nonlinear characteristic, there can be valid operating points when the resistor is attached to the V = 0, I = 0 port, but that V = 0 I = 0 point will always be a valid operating point so unless there's a disturbance to the circuit to shake it from that point, the resistor won't directly cause a change.

Comment: @knzy , but what I see from graph that only when terminals are open we get (0,0) as a operating point but as soon as we introduce a resistor we get some other operating point (a,b) where a is terminal voltage and b is current through load resistor

Comment: Does the conclusion change if the transfer characteristic is continuously differentiable?

Comment: @user215805 I think that both operating points are valid, I think once the resistor is introduced it could technically be in either one of these operating points, but since it "starts" at (0, 0) like I mentioned in my other answer, it seems like it wouldn't go to the other operating point unless it were somehow forced to. But I think this definitely proves that a resistor introduced to a port of nonlinear circuit initially at (0,0) *could potentially* be in a different operating point. According to Thevenin, for a linear circuit it's *impossible.*

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It doesn't seem like it? If the nonlinear device's V-I characteristic were, for example, V = Vo - R*I^2 (R any constant so units work out), it would intersect the resistor R_L's V-I curve at the same point, resulting in the port's (0, 0) operating point, but also intersect at some other point.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany , I don't think so because 1.even if transfer characteristic is continuous differentiable but we still cannot assume linear about a point unless it is given that magnitude of voltage across non linear element is very very small and 2.even if voltage across non linear element is very very small still linearity is only approximation that we generally use (using Taylor's expansion) but actually there will be some small variations (due to higher order terms of Taylor's expansion) and hence operating point will vary!

Comment: So the load line for the resistor intersects the output VI curve of the circuit in two places. But none of the operating points between are viable for the resistor. So in order to move from the zero current operating point to the non zero current point, the current and voltage would need to change instantaneously upon application of the resistor. Normally we consider instantaneous changes impossible.

Comment: A potentiometer could possibly be used to coax the output from one point to another.

Comment: How can adding a resistor **with zero voltage across it** cause current to flow? There was no current flow before the resistor was added, there is no current flow after the resistor was added. What makes us think the behavior of the circuit will change?

Comment: But the voltage between the nodes isn't zero before you add the resistor, is it?

Comment: Once again, I agree with you folks: in the absence of any outside influence, the prevailing operating point will be the (0 V, 0 A) one. However, note that in principle, other operating points can be made *arbitrarily close* to the (0, 0) operating point by varying the load resistance. See this image: https://i.imgur.com/C2whgPe.png and the Desmos sheet to see for yourself: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sflyaflllm. Thus it seems perfectly reasonable to me to believe that with such close operating points, noise/coupling/etc could take the circuit to a nonzero operating point.

Comment: This is basically what @mkeith was saying, but what I'm suggesting is conceptually slightly different in that instead of considering the load resistance to be variable, it could also be a fixed resistance which is small enough such that the operating points are very close, and when it is attached to the circuit, noise moves the circuit to the nonzero operating point.

Comment: @Hearth Here the voltage between the nodes before adding the resistor is indeed 0, note that by definition of the nonlinear device, when I = 0, the device sustains a nonzero voltage which cancels out that of the source.

Comment: Your circuit has multiple solutions, and in one of them, adding the resistor does not affect the circuit.

Comment: @user253751 This has been acknowledged. Again I think the interesting takeaway here is that with a nonlinear circuit there can exist a different stable operating point, but if the circuit is linear then it's impossible.

Answer (score 6):

**If the non-linear circuit has a steady-state voltage**, any resistor to the same voltage can not inject any current and thus no matter what resistance it is, it will be perceived as an open circuit.  But if some external load changes which might affect that voltage, then current will flow and affect the circuit.

Ridiculous Example:

A tiny coin cell at 3.05V with an internal resistance of 100 Ohms has a nonlinear ESR that changes with %SoC, voltage and temperature..  If you attach a 100A 3.05V power supply, there is no change to the battery voltage.  However, an external load voltage would be affected by this connection.

### Practical interpretation.

Say you had a portable nonlinear circuit and wanted to find the average current load without disconnecting the batteries.  Using a programmable power supply with 4 digit V,I,P displays (like the one I just got) Set the voltage lower than what you expect , connect and turn on. Vbat is display and I=0. Now set V to the same voltage

and notice current is still 0 mA.

Cool.

Now raise the voltage 1% ( typical load regulation error) I had 3V from two AAA inside a 3 channel wireless digital thermometer) So I raised in 10 mV increments to verify battery charge raised current momentarily then dropped to read the external supply current where I assume the battery current was now 0.  I could also estimate mAh and ESR of batteries by jogging voltage and computing dV/dI and C= I*dt/dV for the asymptotic decay time after raising the voltage.  Now with my load current at 5 mA s.s.,  I could estimate if the 3 mos battery life met the spec of good batteries or not. I was getting only 2.4V and LCD was getting dim.  I had just charged the alkaline primary batteries to 3V with a digital CC limit of 100 mA and then decided to perform this experiment, while watching TV and thinking about this question.   (It's a Hanmatek 30V 3A)  n.b. charging primary cells is possible but far less efficient than secondary cells. The only risk is corrosion leakage after a long time if using safe current limit.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply resort to ohm's law: in a resistor, I = V/R. If V is zero, which it will be if the two ends of the resistor are at the same potential, then I must also be zero.

Comment: How can you prove that the addition of the resistor doesn't disturb the circuit, changing the potential of the terminals and drawing current? In general attaching a new resistor to a port changes the port's voltage, and the result isn't governed by Ohm's law even for a linear circuit.

Comment: The resistor doesn’t ‘know’ about the rest of the circuit; it only sees the voltage between its terminals.  Similarly, the rest of the circuit can only ‘see’ that the resistance isn’t infinite by passing a current through it.  Perhaps not a formal proof but quite good enough for me.

Comment: If the two terminals of the port are at the same potential, why do you think attaching an external resistance would have any effect?  Can you sketch an example of the non-linear circuit you are asking about?

Comment: @AnalogKid I don't think that it would have an effect, I'm just not sure how to actually prove it. Unfortunately I can't come up with a nonlinear circuit that would disprove it.

Comment: The answer, grasshopper, was inside you all along. - Master Po

Comment: Just because a circuit is non-linear doesn't mean we throw everything out the window and say the circuit can do whatever it wants, violate causality, and hack the internet to start a global thermonuclear war. I don't think proving a resistor with no potential across it has zero current is related to linearity. If you don't believe it for a linear circuit, then I don't think you should believe it for a non-linear circuit. And conversely.

Comment: @mkeith Things get messy when you violate causality. I did that tomorrow and look what happened yesterday as a result!

Comment: @Hearth I knew you were going to say that! Because I am from the future! I hope voltage spike doesn't delete these comments.

Comment: @knzy It would only affect the circuit if there was a current through it

Comment: @mkeith Actually it seems that linearity does make a difference. Someone posted a helpful example in another answer which demonstrates that a nonlinear circuit with a port which initially has 0 open-circuit voltage and 0 current can have multiple valid operating points when a resistive load is attached. However, with a linear circuit *this is not possible*. Consider the Thevenin eq. of a linear circuit with 0 open-circuit voltage: it's just a resistor, so attaching another resistor to it *cannot* draw current.

Comment: The question is which valid operating point the circuit will go to. My guess is that (as I pointed out in my answer to my own question below) since the "initial" operating point of the floating resistor matches the operating point of the (0V, 0A) port, that is the operating point that will manifest unless something else perturbs the circuit and forces it into a another operating point.

Comment: @mkeith See this image for full explanation/example: https://i.imgur.com/C2whgPe.png, based on user215805's example.

Comment: @knzy I think there is a misunderstanding. Initially from the way you worded the question, it sounded like you thought that maybe a resistor could have non-zero current and yet still have zero voltage just because it was connected to a non-linear circuit. That is not possible because of Ohm's law. But now you are wondering if a resistor could somehow trip-up a non linear circuit simply by being attached to the circuit, and take it away from its stable operating point of zero volts.

Comment: I think a Schmitt trigger can probably do the same thing. Have two stable states, one where voltage and current are zero, and another where they are not.

Comment: @mkeith  I already haven't deleted them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a better example of a nonlinear circuit that shows no voltage across the R3 resistor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would call that a linear, dynamic circuit. Where is the nonlinearity?

Comment: steady state can apply to AC as well, but neither R nor C are nonlinear with respect to V/I for a sinusoidal dv/dt

Comment: This is entirely linear, as far as I can tell.

Comment: An example showing something doesnt happen in one situation doesnt prove there isnt some other situation where it doesnt happen.

Comment: @Hearth the diodes are non-linear.

Comment: @Jasen When I said that, there were no diodes.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to add the Zener diodes after the initial comments about linearity.

Answer (score 2):

With no potential difference no current will flow in the resistor.

So you are essentially asking if can a circuit be disturbed without an extra current flowing. I think it should be clear that it cannot.

The only disturbance you're going to get from a resistor is Johnson (thermal) noise, but it could be argued that if the circuit is measuring Johnson noise between the terminals then they are not equipotential (else there would be no signal)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more thought I think this is the best I can come up with, similar to comments made by users in the other thread.

The nonlinear circuit's port of interest is, by the question's premise, at 0 V. Since it's also an open port, then the current between the terminals must also be 0 A.

The isolated resistor, before being attached to the port (and just floating in space somewhere), is clearly not conducting current, which by Ohm's law means its terminal voltage is 0 V.

So the circuit's port voltage/current are identical to the resistor's when it's floating in space, so the "operating point" of the resistor is immediately compatible with the port's when it gets attached, and so nothing changes and the resistor continues to draw no current and feels 0 V.